# Paypal return url calling get method instead of post from android browser

Tags: java, spring, paypal-sandbox

Hi I have integrated PayPal sandbox for testing for my website, when I am purchasing from desktop browser it is calling the correct POST URL, but when I am purchasing from mobile browser it is redirecting to the GET method.

Can anyone help

Comment: Did your issue got resolved? I am facing the same issue.